# Remote Desktop connection repeatedly aborting

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

I connect to my workplace computer using Remote Desktop. After 1-2 minutes the application freezes to tell me after one more minute that the connection was aborted. It then reconnects. Everything works again for 1-2 minutes. Then the process repeats. Probably Forever.
My coworkers do not experience such problems when connecting to the workplace.

My workplace computer:

- Windows 7 32bit

My home computer:

- Windows 7 64bit
- connected to the internet via WLAN-router with integrated ADSL modem (Linksys WAG200G)

Things I already tried to fix the problem:

- disabled the Windows firewall
- disabled the other firewall
- reduced the MTU
- upgraded the firmware on the router
- configured port-forwarding to forward all packets to my home computer

The problem remains unchanged.

What could be the cause of the connection aborts? What else can I try to fix the connection?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your connection via VPN?

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this hundreds of times, and 95% of the time it is a hardware issue, usually a nic card.

Networking hardware.

Router, switch if you have one, Network card, Network Cable.

To start, force your network card to slow down, instead of 100mb full duplex or auto in the device manager, slow it down to 100 half duplex or even 10mb and test it. if it now works, more then likely the network card in your machine is bad. if it doesn't fix it, do the same on your workspace pc.
If it still does not fix it, look at the cabling, swap them out with new cables.
If it still does not fix the problem, swap out the routers.

Another thing you can do, is eliminate your home PC alltogether by going to an internet cafe or someone you know with a PC and try to log in to the remote desktop from there.

My bet is one of the nics in one of your PC's as cables hardly ever go bad unless they are pinched

HTH

Answer (score 1):

If you can, try and ping your remote computer from home, see if you get any packet loss, high ttl etc. I take it you can use the internet/game etc without any problems.